# Unsorted list of people's first names written in only ASCII characters

Tags: names

I realize that this question is too easy for most people, but I am hoping people who type into google, "Example of a list of people's names" can find this.

It will save them the trouble of writing a program to procedurally generate people names or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This particular collection has 189 people's names.

They are in un-sorted order.

```
Alieta
Cameron
Daisy
Dalton
Edmundo
Fiamalua
Hadley
Henry
Jacob
Laijia
Lepeka
Mamao
Mariano
Omar
Quentin
Raven
Ruby
Sioota
Taki
Toakai
Tulimanu
Walker
Yana
Zion
Douglas
Sioota
Hayden
Olivia
Yahya
Hudson
Oscar
Yara
Dana
Finikaso
Jack
Maalosi
Manase
Nisha
Oliver
Patala
Joshua
Teoliga
Edueni
Espinar
Gavin
Tuimanuga
Carter
Gabriel
Leoz
Quinn
Zahra
Alfonso
David
Eselealofa
Eti
Hannah
James
Oakley
Pitoi
Pouesi
Quin
Rasgado
Semprún
Taeia
Taulau
Ulrich
Una
Uriel
Wade
Yael
Yvonne
Zia
Grace
Meauma
Aunese
Dale
Gabriella
Gael
Gemma
Harper
Ielemia
John
Leonardo
Maketi
Querida
Rachel
Teniku
Tulimanu
Warren
William
Zane
Zora
Charles
Harley
Hunter
Kuruisalili
Ryan
Tafalla
Timo
Ulysses
Uma
Alfredo
Calvin
Daniel
Jackson
Laguna
Lotoala
Quiana
Sione
Toakai
Elia
George
Qamar
Urban
Zachary
Zuri
Abellán
Casey
Charlie
Ela
Remy
Rose
Saini
Tomu
Bernabé
Gabrielle
Martín
Quillan
Uday
Yvette
Israel
Vaea
Wyatt
Afemai
Alejandro
Cole
Fernandino
Maibuca
Niu
Olga
Owen
Quinlan
Reyes
Rowan
San
Tuilimu
Walter
Brooke
Dakota
Elisaia
Gaia
Jamie
Maleko
Pola
Teii
Ursula
Wesley
Yolanda
Zara
Zena
Dallas
Diego
Estefania
Ewekia
Harrison
Jane
Octavia
Quenby
Raul
Ray
Riley
Temate
Uriah
Wallace
Whitney
Caleb
Fagalele
Ituaso
Kamtaura
Lagitupu
Maani
Terokoraoi
Tinoga
Vave
Yadira
Yasmin
Jade
Sokomani
Talake
```

Comment: Source of the list?